# Dual Supply from single 24v dc source and 12v regulator

Tags: power-supply, dual

I was thinking about different ways a dual supply could be created, and I was wondering if something along the lines of what I made in this schematic would work. I don't have any kind of formal education in this stuff so excuse me if there is some blatent thing I'm missing.

[image: Would this work, assuming a suitably stable supply?]

Comment: What did you need to power it for?

Comment: I didn't have any particular application in mind. I just had thought of it while I was working on a power supply for a diy ociliscope pre-amp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Regulators won't sink (current, that is)

Your signal reference (ground) in a dual supply configuration needs to be able to both *source* and *sink* current -- in other words, it needs to be able to accept current flow into it as well as provide current flowing out of it.

However, a three-terminal regulator's single-pass-device output can only source current -- there's no path for current to flow *into* the regulator's OUT pin that takes the current where you want it to go (to the GND pin, in your case).  Some regulators simply will not output at all (i.e. the pass device will turn off, leaving no current path from OUT to much of anywhere significant) under those circumstances, while others have a parasitic diode from OUT to IN that will turn on when you try to stuff current into OUT, causing the regulator to get confused.

### Never fear though, the Rail Splitter is here!

Fortunately for you though, dual-supply signal references don't need that much current in most applications, so TI makes a part in TO-92 that is just what you are after: the [TLE2426 "Rail Splitter" virtual ground IC.](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tle2426.pdf)

This part can be used in place of your three-terminal regulator in the schematic you posted to provide a "0V" from the floating supply you want to split that can source *and* sink current (up to 20mA for the TLE2426 by itself, and you can also shove a power op amp voltage follower in there to buffer its output if you need more current).  Furthermore, the TLE2426 output accurately tracks the half-supply mark; your proposal, even with a two-quadrant regulator, would cause asymmetric supply voltages if the 24V supply started to wander off.

Answer (score 2):

This won't work reliably - the 7812 and similar regulators can only source current, they can't sink it.

This will work as long as the current drawn from the -12 is greater than the current drawn from +12, as the regulator will be sourcing current in that situation.

If the current drawn from the +12 is greater than from -12, the regulator would have to sink current - but it can't do that, so the "ground" will shift towards +12, reducing the positive voltage, and increasing the negative voltage.